# Compare dates in JS dont work

Tags: javascript, date, compare

I have this function in JS and its a very strange because works with many dates but with one not..

I have two inputs and with jquery copy the first in the second if the second is minor or is null, and then if i put another greater date in the first, the second date changes to the same at the first.

But I have one case that the first input has 01/05/2013 and in the second has 31/05/2013, if i change the first to 01/06/2013 the second should be change at the same date, but dont do it..

And if with firebug i test it and this function

```
  obtenerFecha(fIni) > obtenerFecha(fFin) // obtenerFecha(01/06/2013) > obtenerFecha(31/05/2013)
```

returns false, and its true!

Here is my code if someone can help me..

```
    function copiarFecha(inicio,fin) {
        var fIni = $("#" + inicio).val();
        var fFin = $("#" + fin).val();
        if ((fFin == "") || obtenerFecha(fIni) > obtenerFecha(fFin)) {
            $("#" + fin).attr('value', fIni);
        }
        return true;
    }


    function obtenerFecha(strFecha) {
        var df = strFecha.split("/");
        if (isNaN(df[0]) || isNaN(df[1]) || isNaN(df[2]) || (df[0] > 31) || (df[1] > 12)) {
            cargaMensaje("KO", "La fecha no es correcta,revísela.");
            return false;
        }
        return new Date(df[2], df[1], df[0]);
```

Thanks.

Comment: It would help, if you could "translate" your sourcecode to english, that would make it easier to understand what you are doing. Could you edit your post to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subtract 1 from the months. http://jsbin.com/eqozic/2/

**month**

Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for January to 11 for December.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 1):

Months in Javascript Date are in range 0-11 not 1-12 so your new Date(2013, 5 ,31) translates to 2013,06,01 which is 2013 May 01.